# "CreateFile() Error: 5" keep showing on my R studio console and Jupyter Notebook Prompt

Tags: python, r, windows

Error Message:

[image: Error Message]

Everything works as usual in R or Python, only the Error keeps showing and it's so annoying.

Please help me to have a look at this.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide detailed information about your problem, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and what you did try before posting. Please, check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question for more details as well.

Comment: Also, it is not a good idea to insert images to display text.

Comment: Does this happen when you try to run a program, or just when you start the console?

Comment: @alan.elkin Thank you.

Comment: @JohnGordon This also happens when I try to run a program

Answer (score 0):

Though not recommend running notebook server by admin, but i solved this issue with "run as admin".
you can look for more details in below link.

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1385